# Creating Monte Carlo data for Dummy Variables in R

Tags: r, matrix, montecarlo

I'm setting up an Monte Carlo simulation, and I have been trying to create a set of dummy variables for 180 countries and 12 time periods. Given the large amount of data points, is there a shorter way to create dummy variables for time and country fixed effects without pulling it out of an excel file?

For Example

```
   F.T(1)  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. 1, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0......(Extends until 180 countries)
   F.T(2)  0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0......(Extrends until 180 countries)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: R has lots of functions to generate "random" data, and they are very easy to use.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be easier/faster to create all data with `rbinom` first and then convert it into a matrix instead of calling `rbinom` 12 times. That is:

```
set.seed(45)
t <- rbinom(180*12, 1, 0.5)
dim(t) <- c(180, 12)
```

Just to see if there 's a difference, here's a benchmark

```
# I use simplify = TRUE here.
FUN1 <- function(n, a) {
    set.seed(45)
    replicate(n, rbinom(a, 1, .5), simplify = TRUE)
}
FUN2 <- function(n, a) {
    set.seed(45)
    t <- rbinom(n*a, 1, 0.5)
    dim(t) <- c(a, n)
    t
}
require(rbenchmark)
benchmark(t1 <- FUN1(1000, 12000), t2 <- FUN2(1000, 12000), 
            order="elapsed", replications=5)

#                      test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
# 2 t2 <- FUN2(1000, 12000)            5   3.991    1.000     3.859    0.111
# 1 t1 <- FUN1(1000, 12000)            5   5.337    1.337     4.785    0.472


identical(t1, t2)
# [1] TRUE
```

To answer your question in comment:

```
w  <- rep(diag(12)[1:9, ], N)
dim(w) <- c(9, 12*N)
w <- t(w)
colnames(w) <- paste0("t", 1:9)
```

Or even better:

```
w2 <- do.call(rbind, replicate(N, diag(12)[, 1:9], simplify = FALSE))
colnames(w2) <- paste0("t", 1:9)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. One last question, just a slight variation of the previous question in the comment(I'm talking about the exact same matrix set-up instead the numbers are alternating differently now). What if I want something like
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
instead of 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 ect. in a matrix

Comment: don't quite follow. you want this as a matrix?

Comment: Yeah, a matrix. For example, for the first column the first 12 numbers are '1' and the rest '0'. For the second column, the first 12 numbers are '0' and the next 12 are '1' and the rest '0'...And so on.

Comment: your second column description is not valid I think. you've accounted already for 12 1's and 12 0's and then what do you mean by "rest 0"? Do you mean for the second column as: 0, 12 1's, 11 0's?

Comment: I'm sorry, what I meant was a matrix(rows=N*12 and columns=12)

Answer (score 3):

Using replicate with your random number generator of choice should do the trick 
Here is an example using a simple binomial distribution with prob = 1/2

```
replicate(12, rbinom(180, 1, .5), simplify=FALSE)
```

Comment: I think he might want `replicate(12, ...` instead, but it is hard to say for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I'm trying to generate dummy variables with 12 columns and 180 rows that takes on alternating values of 0 and 1. Your answer is very helpful nonetheless.

Comment: @SamChu, in that case, you might want to use `simplify=TRUE` (but leave the `180` & `12` where they are, as `simplify`ing will transpose your matrix)

Comment: @RicardoSaporta is there a faster way to do something like this?
t1 <- replicate(N,matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)))
t2 <- replicate(N,matrix(c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)))
t3 <- replicate(N,matrix(c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)))
t4 <- replicate(N,matrix(c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)))
t5 <- replicate(N,matrix(c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)))
t6 <- replicate(N,matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)))
t7 <- replicate(N,matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)))
t8 <- replicate(N,matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)))
t9 <- replicate(N,matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)))
FT <- cbind(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9)

Comment: yes, you can use assign and paste. Details wont fit in the comments section.  I would suggest posting a new question and linking back.